# Generating GCM Registration ID every time

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a question regarding `GCM` **registration ID**.
I saw in documents it asks to save the generate ID for some time say 7 days.
To reduce the complexity, I am thinking of generating this ID everytime and send it to server so server can use it to send message back to Client.
My question is

1. If server sends message back to Client within few hours, Can there be an issue with this ID?
2. Are there any issues with generating this ID every time instead of saving it.

Answer (score 2):

I use the same method as you suggested, and so far had no issues with this.

1. The generated ID is fine if used hours after registering it.
2. No problem registering the device each time. Usually the returned ID is the same anyway.